# Could not find method classpath() for arguments

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

this is my build.gradle

Startup failed

```
build script {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}


dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
}



all projects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies must be inside in javascript section as like as

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        ------
    }
}
```